# Splitting string into array of strings causing NumberFormatException

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I am having an extremely difficult time splitting each line from the text file into an array of strings and using it like I need to. The split() seems to work okay. I end up having an array of strings, where the first slot of the strings array contains a number that I need to parse as an int, to continue my code. For some reason, I keep getting the error shown below that I can't seem to figure out.

My goal is it to simply store every line of the text file that contains letters, in an array, and parse the number which is going to be the first value of the line, as an integer. Once I accomplish this, I need to be able to use every preceding group of letters independently, so I am trying to get those in an array as well.

I appreciate any help with this.

Many thanks in advance!

NOTE: numGrammars is the first number shown on the first line of the text file.

My Code

```
    numGrammars = Integer.parseInt(fin.next());
    System.out.println("Num Grammars:" + numGrammars);


    for(int v=0; v < numGrammars; v++){
       int numVariables = Integer.parseInt(fin.next());
       System.out.printf("numVariables: %s", numVariables);

        for(int z=0; z < numVariables; z++){
            //reads in variable line
            String line = fin.nextLine();
            String[] strings = line.split(" ");

            for(int m=0; m < strings.length; m++){
               int numRules = Integer.parseInt(strings[0]);
               //All other array slots in strings array should be groups of letters on group per slot...

            }   
        }
    }
```

Console Output

```
Num Grammars:2
numVariables: 3Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at Methods.readFile(Methods.java:34)
at Main.main(Main.java:12)
```

Text file I am reading from:

```
1
3
2 S AB BB
3 A BB a b
2 B b c
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to parse aplhabets in place of digits. thats why its throwing `NumberFormatException` may be for char `S`

Comment: Nope, the next character is not S it is the number 2. When I print out strings[0] directly with out parsing, it prints out 2. When I try to parse it as an int then print it out I get this error.

Comment: Then it could be possible that it will be adding whitespace try to use `String.trim()`. `Integer.parseInt(" 2")` will throw exception. May be its better to show us the whole code.

Comment: The error message shows that you are trying to `parseInt` an empty string.

Comment: That doesn't make sense though, because when I `System.out.println(strings[0]);` it prints out the number 2 like it should.

Comment: @MHZ Better you show your whole code. Its not possible to happen like that. If its int string then it will definitely parse without exception. What I see is `String line = fin.nextLine();` in for loop and `numGrammars = Integer.parseInt(fin.next());` this could be problem and hard to understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: No code is left out of the loop this is all my code. strings[0] should be strings[0] because the is the only part of the line that is a number. Replacing 0 with an m, would try to parse strings as an integer as well. I am still developing this program, there is no functionality yet. First I need to successfully parse string[0] which will always contain a number of type string.

Comment: Each iteration of the 'm' for loop corresponds to a line after the first two numbers of the text file. Every line is also one case I need to build my program around. Every line contains an integer following by a groups of letters, so first I need to read in the integer, as an integer, to successfully manipulate the preceeding groups of strings, Make sense?

Comment: Like I said there is not functionality yet. I need to successfully parse strings[0] as an int first before I can build the functionality, which is what I am having the most trouble with.

Comment: @MHZ In place of `fin.next()` use only `fin.nextLine();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only use `fin.nextLine()`.  After the call to `next()`, the cursor is right after the numVariables value `3`, but **before** the newline.  When you call `nextLine()` after that, it returns everything between the cursor and the newline, which is an empty string!  Using `nextLine()` each time always places the cursor after the newline, and everything is OK.

```
numGrammars = Integer.parseInt(fin.nextLine());
System.out.println("Num Grammars:" + numGrammars);


for(int v=0; v < numGrammars; v++){
   int numVariables = Integer.parseInt(fin.nextLine());
   System.out.printf("numVariables: %s", numVariables);

    for(int z=0; z < numVariables; z++){
        //reads in variable line
        String line = fin.nextLine();
        String[] strings = line.split(" ");

        for(int m=0; m < strings.length; m++){
           int numRules = Integer.parseInt(strings[0]);
           //All other array slots in strings array should be groups of letters on group per slot...

        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You don't say what fin is, so I can't say what it does for next() versus nextLine(), but perhaps you are picking up the newline character in your string.

Comment: This is an speculation that would be better posted as a comment and not an answer.